# Using multind with bookdown?

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

Has anyone else tried to do this?

I have

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multind}
```

in my preamble, and the appropriate

```
\makeindex
```

statements also in the preamble and

```
\printindex
```

in my afterbody.

However, no indices appear when building the book.  I only get them if I manually `makeindex` each of the indices and then manually `pdflatex` the book .tex file in the _book subdirectory.

For what it's worth, I know `multind` is archaic, but I also tried the split approach first. I used the `multind` approach as a dead simple one that I thought ought to work.

Comment: Did you try https://ctan.org/pkg/manyind? No extra programs and only one makeindex call looks interesting to me.

Comment: @RalfStubner, Thanks!  That does appear to work.  I like the coding approach, as well.  (Does not answer the question I posed directly, I note... I imagine it might be very difficult to get makeindex to run on arbitrary index files in bookdown.)

Comment: I could imagine that `latexmk` can do that correctly, either in it's script variant or the emulation provided y `tinytex`. Without a [mcve] I am not really inclined to investigate this, though.